# Sticky Nav element - hide then show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sticky nav I'm working on, I was able to gather some code from some other posts, however I'm running into one issue, the nav area I'm hiding after scroll won't show back up when scrolling to the top of the page. I attempted to write an else if statement, but no luck, thanks.

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($("#navheader").offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop)
    $("#navheader").css({"display":"block","top":"0px", "left":"0px"});
    else
    $("#navheader").css({"display":"none"});
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This might be easier**

Looks like the issue was that you need a `()` after `scrollTop` on `window`.

```
var n = $("#navheader");//get nav
var nh = n.offset().top;//get nav offset
var go = true;//toggle execute so it doesn't fire on every match
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wh = $(this).scrollTop();//window scroll
    if(wh <= nh && !go) {//show
        n.show();
        go = true;
    } else if (wh > nh && go) {//hide
        n.hide();
        go = false;
    }
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/cxJ6a/

**edit:** added a `go` toggle to stop fire on every match of the if/then. this way it fires once each way.

Answer (score 0):

If you console.log:

```
console.log($("#navheader").offset().top)
```

On the scroll event, you will see that once the IF statement becomes true it will return always 0. Since the element is fixed and it has top: 0 it will always have 0.

The solution you ask?

Make the offest global variable and check it.

```
var navOff = $("#navheader").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(navOff <= $(window).scrollTop())
        $("#navheader").css({"display":"block","top":"0px", "left":"0px"});
    else
        $("#navheader").css({"display":"none"});
});
```

But since your $("#navheader") is probably set to display: none and it will probably return 0 even this way...

So you have a few options.

1. Make some holder of the navigation and target it's offest.
2. Hard code the value.
3. Make it visibility: hidden; instead of display: none; (that way you can target the offest)